# OpenCV, Numpy, Efficiently Calculate Number of Pixels Meeting Arbitrary Criteria as Function of all Channels

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, numpy, opencv

Suppose I want to sum the number of pixels that meet a given criteria, which is determined by some arbitrary function of the values of each of its four channels, such as in the code example below.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('test.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
height, width = img.shape[:2]

count = 0
for y in range(height):
  for x in range(width):
    # blue, green, red, alpha channels
    if img[y][x][0] > 200 and img[y][x][1] < 210 and img[y][x][2] > 230 and img[y][x][3] > 128:
      count += 1

print(count)
```

Is there a more efficient way to compute `count` using built in Numpy functions?

Comment: `count = (img > [200, 210, 230, 128]).all(axis=-1).sum()`

Comment: Instead of `img[y][x][0]` use `img[...,0]` and so on with the same comparison operators and `&` for the `AND-ing` part.

Comment: @Eric, what if only one of the channels needs to be smaller than a certain value while the others should be larger?

Comment: Then do what @Divakar suggests